# Can Hartree-Fock be considered the quantum mechanical "Monopole" term in a quantum mechanical multipole expansion?

Tags: theoretical-chemistry

From what I understand, Hartree-Fock simplifies the exact electron-electron interaction with its two electron integrals. It reminds me of the classical energy of a charge distribution combined with the multipole expansion. Is it valid to think of it in this way?

Comment: One thing I'd like add is that Hartree-Fock does not simplify the "exact electron-electron interaction with its two electron integral" because electron-electron interaction is a two-body interaction term by definition. The simplification of Hartree-Fock is that the ansatz is a Slater-determinant. By the way, this is also a nice analogy since it is the same for multipole expansion: the interaction there is still a sum (integral) of two-body interactions, just the 'ansatz' the expansion is different.

Comment: And in this sense, you could say that Hartree-Fock theory is the 'mopole' term of the full configuration interaction expansion. I really like your analogy.